# Haskell error No instance for (RealFrac a0) arising from a use of

Tags: haskell, type-systems

I'm an absolute beginner with Haskell and I'm trying to build a list comprehension that generates prime numbers. I get an error with I try to call my function. I am really not sure what is causing the error. Can anyone explain what the problem is in terms an absolute beginner would understand? I am only at the basics of the Haskell typesystem.

Code:

```
roundupsqrt x = ceiling (sqrt x)

listnthprimes x = take x [y|y<-[1..], odd y, all (/=0) (map (y`mod`) [2..(roundupsqrt y)])]
```

Error:

```
No instance for (RealFrac a0) arising from a use of `listnthprimes'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Integral a => RealFrac (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
In the expression: listnthprimes 6
In an equation for `it': it = listnthprimes 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sqrt` is defined as `Floating a => a -> a`; you’re passing it an integer. [`fromIntegral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3afromIntegral) would work:

```
roundupsqrt x = ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral x))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I actually tested the roundupsqrt function by itself first and had no problem. I guess if I call that function in ghci it converts my integer parameter into a float? But when I used it in my prime number function no such conversion took place?

Comment: @user3561192: That’s right. When you have a numeric literal, it might be able to become a few things, but in `listnthprimes`, `y` has to come from a range of integers only.